# Front-End solution for only allowing a single submission on a form even after page refresh

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, frontend

I'm trying to find a solution for only having a form submit once for a front end project I'm working on. The page should only allow for one submission and any subsequent attempts to submit should be ignored. I've thought of somehow using cookies but I'm not too familiar with them so I don't really know if that is the right approach. I'm pretty much at a loss right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localstorage`. Use the `getItem` and `setItem` methods to retrieve and store the values:

```
localStorage.setItem("isDisabled", "true"); // to store the value
localStorage.getItem("isDisabled"); // to retrieve the value
```

Another solution could be to store the boolean value in the database and make an API call to store and retrieve its value. This way, it will work across different browsers and machines.

P.S. localstorage accepts only string values and is cleared upon clearing browser's cache.